# packet download speed drops for ubuntu 20.04.05 Server

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have a virtual machine in VMware Workstation 16.2.3. runing in Windows 10 Pro

I managed a few months ago to install Ubuntu 20.04.5 Server.
The idea of creating this virtual machine is to be able to test different web applications, for that reason I have installed several versions of php and I have configured them to run as a virtual host; all this works correctly.

after a few months I decided to check for updates and the system tells me that there are 119 updates for the different packages... etc:

php 5.6.*,php 7.2, php 7.4.* y php 8.1.*

when executing the command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

only the ***first package*** in the list is downloaded successfully at a stable speed; from the second packet the speed drops rapidly to 99b speed; it doesn't even reach 1kb. 4 days ETA

I'm really baffled since canceling the download and repeating the upgrade command; it again downloads the previously queued package at a good speed but the second package is slowed down on download.

so on with all the packages; I've had to manually cancel and upgrade about 110 times. this exhausts and I know that it is not correct.

The problem is that ***I don't know how to attack this problem***; since in another virtual machine with the same VMWare setup running ubuntu 22.04.1 I don't have this scenario... but I can't do all the tests in this version and I am forced to use the previous one 20.04...

my doubt; How can I or with what can I verify if my installation of this virtual machine is correct or if my virtual machine is correctly configured. the idea is to determine what is affecting the correct download of the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's been so long since you last updated this machine, you might try cleaning your apt cache. See [this thread for tips](https://askubuntu.com/a/613278):

Comment: zorry but is server version, not desktop. my mistake...

Comment: The answer in that thread that I linked to still applies. Use the apt commands as demonstrated.